# Replace the latter of two identical strings enclosed in quotes via sed in coffeescript

Tags: regex, sed, coffeescript

This is driving me nuts. I'm using `sed` in coffeescript to replace a line in a config file that looks as follows:

```
'username' => 'username',
```

My code looks like this:

`commands.push "sed -i '' '119 s/\(.\)username.,$/\1" + dbinfo.dbUser + "\1,/g' '" + tmpAppDir + "/drupal/sites/default/settings.php'"`

This should totally work, except coffeescript is interpreting my backreferences as octal escape sequences (Not allowed under strict mode.

I wouldn't have to use backreferences if I was able to escape single-quotes, but that doesn't really seem possible in this context.

Any help?

Comment: You might have to double escape everything: `\\(`, `\\1`, etc.

Comment: I think we can break the problem down a little here. On the one hand, you are trying to determine what arguments to pass to a spawned "sed" process to achieve the transformation and on the other, you are trying to determine how to get coffeescript to do that. There's actually an intermediate problem b/c you're probably calling a shell (maybe "sh") to parse the command into a program ("sed") and its arguments (["-i", "", ...]). Can you clarify what you're doing with "commands" after this?

Comment: @RobStarling -- Yes, I'm writing this as an app for [Koding](http://www.koding.com). What happens next is that the list of commands in the "commands" array is run in Koding's special ("Special" in the sense of "Special Ed", not "Special Forces") console.

Comment: @Blender -- I tried that, I think it's causing compilation to fail.

Comment: What if you triple or quadruple the backslashes? The root of the problem (as Rob Starling notes) is that you're using several languages that all want to use the same escape character.

Comment: @muistooshort -- I've tried triple and quadruple now; triple gives syntax errors and it seems quadruple compiles, but I have another error somewhere that's preventing me from ascertaining whether the quadruple actually works in the context of `sed`. Will report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your code in pure javascript with `` ` ``

```
`commands.push("sed -i '' '119 s/\(.\)username.,$/\1" + dbinfo.dbUser + "\1,/g' '" + tmpAppDir + "/drupal/sites/default/settings.php'");`
```

It's not an elegant solution, but it's an easy fix for your code.

Comment: Waitwaitwaitwait... I can just enclose that line in backticks and it runs as pure JavaScript? That's really good to know if so!